# Rundeck - Skip unhealthy nodes

Tags: rundeck

Here is my problem with rundeck.

I have a job that is set to run on any one of the 4 nodes (say node 1...node 4) at any given point in time
To achieve this I set the Orchestrator option under nodes to Random Subset and the count to 1.

But how can I avoid this job to skip a node that is unhealthy? This is needed so that we don't have to worry about altering the monitoring job during server maintenance as the job can run on any of the remaining healthy nodes.

Without the option to skip unhealthy nodes, the monitoring job fails when it picks an unhealthy node randomly which is under maintenance.

Comment: You can do that using the Health Checks feature: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/healthchecks.html#overview, Health Checks is only present on Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise"), in that way you can use a  node filter only for healthy nodes like `healthcheck:status: HEALTHY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the [Health Checks feature](https://%20docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/healthchecks.html#overview), Health Checks is only present on Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise"), in that way you can use a node filter only for healthy nodes like `healthcheck:status: HEALTHY`.